# I can't parse JSON by JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to send some data to JQuery by JSON. There is my code below:

```
$name = "test";
$answer = array("code" => 1, "name" => $name);
echo json_encode($answer);
```

```js
console.log(data); 
var response = JSON.parse(data);
```

Console says:

```
{"code":1,"name":"test"}
```

> VM635:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 2
>
> at JSON.parse ()
>
> at Object.onAjaxSuccess [as success] (auth.js:32)
>
> at u (jquery.js:2)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
>
> at k (jquery.js:2)
>
> at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.js:2)

Help me :O

Comment: `data` has already been deserialised. You don't need to parse it again. Simply remove the call to `JSON.parse()` and your code will work

Comment: How I can take something from variable data?

Comment: `data.yourPropertyNameHere`

Comment: you just need to access as `data.code`

Comment: When I tried to access `data.code` console told me `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I think you must remove JSON.parse.... because you already parse in json with json_encode

Comment: Your solution is correct, but note that it's nothing to do with `json_encode`. It's because the OP is most likely using `$.ajax` and has set the `dataType` to `json` s jQuery is automatically deserialising it for him.

Comment: agreed with @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Let jQuery do the work:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.php", function( data ) {
     console.log(data);
}
```

That's just a wrapper to $.ajax.  When you send the data from the PHP, you should send Content-Type too, not absolutely necessary but definitely best practice.